# Cannot read property username of undefinded discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am making a ship command, the error messages work but the shipping does not. I always get this error: `Type Error: Cannot read property "username" of undefined`. Can someone help me to fix it?
Here is my code:

```
const { DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: 'ship',
    description: "Ship two users!",
    execute(message, args) {
    const user = message.mentions.members.first();
    const user2 = message.mentions.members.first(+1) ;
    const images = [(1-100) code is different, put every number there]
    const result = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    const error = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#000000")
    .setTitle("Ship")
    .setDescription("There was an error: Check if you mentioned a user other than you!")
    .setFooter(message.author.username)
    .setTimestamp()
    ;

    if(!user) return message.reply(error);
    if(!user2) user2 = message.author.username;
    if(user.id === message.author.id) return message.reply(error);

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#2A333E")
    .setTitle("Ship")
    .setDescription(user2.user.username + " + " + user.user.username + " =")
    .addField(images[result] + "%" , "Is this good or not so good?")
    .setFooter(message.author.username)
    .setTimestamp()
    ;

    message.channel.send(embed)
    }}
```

Comment: can you provide the full stack trace? it would help us identify which line we need to focus on

Comment: I already looked, which line it is. It is in the embed const, the description, so line 28.

Answer (score 0):

`if(!user2) user2 = message.author.username;`

This is the problematic line - you're setting the value of `user2` to equal the author's username. Try setting it to equal just `message.author` instead.

Additionally, you're trying to retrieve the `.user` property from `User` objects, which does not exist (since it's already a `User` object.) You'll need to change `user2.user.username` and `user.user.username` to just `user2.username` and `user.username`

Comment: First, thank you for your help! I now do not get errors anymore, but the users in the embed are only shown as undefined.